DISM - how to download offline installer
This dism command install MediaFeaturePack for Windows 10 N LTSC:
dism /online /add-capability /capabilityname:Media.MediaFeaturePack~~~~0.0.1.0

Is there a way to somehow modify it to get an offline installers for all of the packages it's trying to install, without actually installing anything?

That command is an offline command.
